# How to use an Event Hub Trigger in a Java Azure Function

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-java-sdk, java-annotations

I am attempting to create a Java Azure Function that triggers off of an Azure Event Hub. I am following these code snippets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=java#example

Here is my code:

```
package com.function;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.function.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;

public class function {

    @FunctionName("MTI")
    public void EventHubProcess(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "mticallhub", connection = "EHubConnectionString"), String message, final ExecutionContext context) 
    {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request: " + message);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get when building:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project func-MTI-test-zyg-001: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/JavaStuff/FunctionApps/func-MTI-test-zyg-001/src/main/java/com/function/Function.java:[34,105] illegal start of type
```

Here is the error popup in VSCode:
[image: popup error in VSCode]

I've been looking for hours and exhausted page after page of Google searches. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change

```
@EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "mticallhub", connection = "EHubConnectionString"), String message, final ExecutionContext context)
```

to

```
@EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "mticallhub", connection = "EHubConnectionString") String message, final ExecutionContext context)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thank you so much!