# Azure function Eventhub trigger is throwing NPE

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have created an az function on java spring boot with eventhub trigger. I have followed the MS documentation for it. But it looks like it is failing while receiving the events from EventHub. Here are the FunctionHandler and FunctionProcessor classes.`@Slf4j
public class FunctionHandler extends FunctionInvoker<String, Boolean>{

```
@FunctionName("functionProcessor")
public void run(@EventHubTrigger(name = "message", dataType = "string",
eventHubName = "satya-eh", connection = "EVH_CONN")List<String> messages,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java Event Hub trigger received " + messages.size() +" messages");
    for(String m : messages) {
        context.getLogger().info("Logged the Event: "+m);
        handleRequest(m, context);
    }
}
```

}`

FunctionProcessor.java

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FunctionProcessor implements Function<String, Boolean>{

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(String message) {
        log.info("Received message from Eventhubs: "+message);
        return true;
    }

}
```

host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
    },
    "extensions": {
        "eventHubs": {
            "batchCheckpointFrequency": 5,
            "eventProcessorOptions": {
                "maxBatchSize": 256,
                "prefetchCount": 512
            },
            "initialOffsetOptions": {
                "type": "fromStart",
                "enqueuedTimeUtc": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "None",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Function.functionProcessor": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

While going trhough the 'Failure' on app insight I found below as message.

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.functionProcessor Result: Failure
Exception: NullPointerException: 
Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:55)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:62)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker.handleRequest(FunctionInvoker.java:117)
    at com.alldata.function.FunctionHandler.run(FunctionHandler.java:23)
    ... 16 more
```

Here is the Call Stack mentioned:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108)
Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:96)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase+<Invoke>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs:82)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.cs:20)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__33.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:581)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:527)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:306)
```

Comment: Could you please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480309/how-to-use-an-event-hub-trigger-in-a-java-azure-function)

Comment: But the Thread you are refering to and my issues are different. My function is running but failing on incoming requests

Comment: Can you check the code at `FunctionHandler.java:23`? What is happening over there. My guess is that may be `messages` may be coming over as null